# Can I use setters over a bundle when creating a new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

When I first started android development, it was drilled into my head that creating a fragment should always be accomplished through a static method you create that uses the fragments default constructor, assigns arguments through a bundle, sets the bundle on the fragment and then returns it. For example:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance() {
    MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("lifesAnswer", 42);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
```

To my vague understanding, the reason we do this is because android will now implicitly handle restoring the fragment and its arguments without any additional work should that outcome happen and restoring is necessary.

Now what if I used the fragments interface in here to set an arbitrary value that could be passed into `newInstance()` as a parameter. For example:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someValue) {
    MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
    frag.setInstanceValue(someValue); // using a public setter
    return frag;
}
```

for sake of clarity, `setInstanceValue()` is just your standard setter like:

```
public void setInstanceValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Is this approach perfectly legal and safe to do. For context in practice here, I have a fragment that will be reused multiple times in a viewpager and all that is different about it is some text and the containers background image. I could just pass the resolved integer values and set them in the bundle for example passing `R.String.my_string` then setting that in the bundle and using it later but it got me thinking. Is it acceptable to implement the second approach or should I always use the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment {

String valueOne;

String valueTwo;

public static YourFragment create(String valueOne, String valueTwo) {
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    fragment.valueOne = valueOne;
    fragment.valueTwo = valueTwo;
    return fragment;
}

}
```

There is no need of using setters here.

Or use `FragmentArgs` https://github.com/sockeqwe/fragmentargs library.